# Highcharts - init with different vertical/horizontal config based on browser width, also after resize

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, highcharts

Our responsive web app needs to adjust charts to be rendered with vertical configuration when windows size is, or is resized as, narrow. With wider screen sizes the charts are rendered with horizontal configuration.

What would a best way to achieve this?

One way would be to first load the chart with config conditionally based on $(window).width() value. Then define [redraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw) function and reinit chart with different config if window width has changed past break point.

Comment: Maybe simplaer is set width of container chart as 100%?

Comment: Container width already is 100% – Highcharts is already that responsive. But the point here is that for handheld device we need different chart configurations. As in this case we are displaying charts vertically the get the data to be viewed with all the screen estate. However I have already found a proper solution for this problem, going to post here soon.

Comment: In that case, you need to check a window width or screen and then apply options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible since [Highcharts 5.0. responsive features](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/responsive).